# Website w/SVN: Working Copy: Configuring Apache httpd.conf for local svn checkout - HOWTO?

Tags: windows, svn, apache, localhost, httpd.conf

I have worked with SVN, and with Apache but not together.

My customer has a live site at one address, and an SVN repository on another machine at another address.

I have checked out the whole 9 yards to a directory on my local (Windows XP) machine which is running Apache/2.0.59. (There are generally no problems configuring local sites.)

I get 3 directories in the checkout:
branches,
tags,
trunk

Which one should I use for my DocumentRoot ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You're lucky they don't have a big project.  I've seen developers run out of hard drive space by checking out the TTB (tags, trunk, and branches)!

Answer (score 1):

You're probably checking out the wrong directory. Usually you check out either `trunk`, or a subdirectory of `branches` or `tags`. Otherwise you could end up checking out dozens of copies of the code, in slightly different versions.

As for the document root, that depends on how the project is organized. It could be the same as the directory you checked out, or it could be a subdirectory. The latter is more likely, since the project will probably contain some code that shouldn't be accessible from the web.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should use the one you need to use. Any that directory can contain sources. And we don't know which one you need in this particular case.